# Not in outer par mode error with table

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report} \usepackage[english,greek]{babel} \usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,etoolbox,caption}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{multirow,enumitem}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usepackage{mathtools,slashed}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfornament,tikzrput}         
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text}
\newcommand{\pvec}[1]{\vec{#1}\mkern2mu\vphantom{#1}}
\newcommand{\gear}[5]{%
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#1} {%
    [rotate=(\i-1)*360/#1]  (0:#2)  arc (0:#4:#2) {[rounded corners=.8pt]
     -- (#4+#5:#3)  arc (#4+#5:360/#1-#5:#3)} --  (360/#1:#2)}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arc}{arc}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!20}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand*\mygraybox[1]{%
\colorbox{light-gray}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}
\lstnewenvironment{mat} 
{\lstset{language=mathematica,mathescape,columns=flexible}}
{}
\tikzstyle arrowstyle=[>=stealth',scale=0.8]
\tikzstyle directed=[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
    mark=at position .6 with {\arrow[arrowstyle]{>}}}}]
\tikzstyle reverse directed=[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
    mark=at position .5 with {\arrowreversed[arrowstyle]{>};}}}]
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} 
\usetikzlibrary{fillbetween}

\DeclareMathOperator{\csch}{csch}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, includefoot, headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}

\begin{document}



\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily{Προσανατολισμού}}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\sffamily{Φυσική β' λυκείου}}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{Φροντιστήρια {\bf ΚΙΝΗΤΡΟΝ}}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\setcounter{page}{107} 


\vspace*{2cm}
{\parindent=0cm
{\Huge{Κεφάλαιο 4.3}}
\vspace*{3cm}

{\fontsize{80}{100}\selectfont {Θερμοδυναμική}} }
\vspace*{2cm}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ticks=none,
ymin=0, ymax=3,
samples=150,
width=5cm, height=4cm,
xmin=0, xmax=3.2,
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center,
y axis line style={thick,-stealth'},
x axis line style={thick,-stealth'},
x label style={font=\small, below},
y label style={font=\small, above},
x tick label style={font=\small},
xtick={},
xticklabels={},
y tick label style={font=\small},
ytick={},
yticklabels={},
xlabel=$V$, ylabel=$p$
, axis on top]


\draw[very thick,RedViolet,directed,fill=gray!40] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates{(axis cs: 1,2) (axis cs: 1.5,2.5) (axis cs: 2,1.5)(axis cs:2.3 ,1.6)(axis cs:2.5 ,0.8)(axis cs: 2,1) (axis cs: 1.5,1.7) (axis cs: 1,2)};

\node[font=\small] at (axis cs: 0.8,2.25){A};
\node[font=\small] at (axis cs: 2.6,0.5){B};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ticks=none,
ymin=0, ymax=3,
samples=150,
width=5cm, height=4cm,
xmin=0, xmax=3.2,
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center,
y axis line style={thick,-stealth'},
x axis line style={thick,-stealth'},
x label style={font=\small, below},
y label style={font=\small, above},
x tick label style={font=\small},
xtick={},
xticklabels={},
y tick label style={font=\small},
ytick={},
yticklabels={},
xlabel=$V$, ylabel=$p$
, axis on top]

\draw[gray!50,fill=gray!50] plot[smooth] coordinates{(axis cs: 1,2) (axis cs: 1.5,2.5) (axis cs: 2,1.5)(axis cs:2.3 ,1.6)(axis cs:2.5 ,0.8)}--(axis cs:2.5 ,0)--(axis cs:1 ,0)--cycle;
\draw[very thick,RedViolet,directed,name path=A] plot[smooth] coordinates{(axis cs: 1,2) (axis cs: 1.5,2.5) (axis cs: 2,1.5)(axis cs:2.3 ,1.6)(axis cs:2.5 ,0.8)};

\draw [thick, dotted,-](axis cs: 1,0)--(axis cs: 1,2);
\draw [thick, dotted,-](axis cs: 2.5,0)--(axis cs: 2.5,0.8);
\node[font=\small] at (axis cs: 0.8,2.25){A};
\node[font=\small] at (axis cs: 2.7,0.55){B};
\node[font=\small] at (axis cs: 1.8,1){(1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ticks=none,
ymin=0, ymax=3,
samples=150,
width=5cm, height=4cm,
xmin=0, xmax=3.2,
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center,
y axis line style={thick,-stealth'},
x axis line style={thick,-stealth'},
x label style={font=\small, below},
y label style={font=\small, above},
x tick label style={font=\small},
xtick={},
xticklabels={},
y tick label style={font=\small},
ytick={},
yticklabels={},
xlabel=$V$, ylabel=$p$
, axis on top]

\draw[gray!50,fill=gray!50] plot[smooth] coordinates{(axis cs:2.5 ,0.8) (axis cs: 2,1) (axis cs: 1.5,1.7) (axis cs: 1,2)}--(axis cs:1 ,0)--(axis cs:2.5 ,0)--cycle;
\draw[very thick,RedViolet,directed,name path=A] plot[smooth] coordinates{(axis cs:2.5 ,0.8) (axis cs: 2,1) (axis cs: 1.5,1.7) (axis cs: 1,2)};

\draw [thick, dotted,-](axis cs: 1,0)--(axis cs: 1,2);
\draw [thick, dotted,-](axis cs: 2.5,0)--(axis cs: 2.5,0.8);
\node[font=\small] at (axis cs: 0.8,2.25){A};
\node[font=\small] at (axis cs: 2.7,0.55){B};
\node[font=\small] at (axis cs: 1.8,0.5){(2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}



\begin{shaded}
\begin{flushright}{\sffamily{Υπόδειξη 1}}\end{flushright}

\noindent{\sffamily\textcolor{Mahogany}{ 1. Υπολογισμός έργου αντιστρεπτής μεταβολής αερίου: }}\\ 
Σε μια αντιστρεπτή μεταβολή το έργο του αερίου μπορεί να υπολογιστεί \\
$\vartriangleright$ Αν η μεταβολή είναι ισόθερμη, ισόχωρη, ισοβαρής ή αδιαβατική από τις σχέσεις που ισχύουν σε κάθε περίπτωση.\\
$\vartriangleright$ Αν η μεταβολή δεν είναι κυκλική από το εμβαδόν που ορίζεται από τη γραμμή της μεταβολής και τον άξονα των όγκων στο διάγραμμα $p-V$ (κατ" απόλυτη τιμή). \\ 
$\vartriangleright$ Αν η μεταβολή είναι κυκλική από το εμβαδόν που περικλείεται από τη γραμμή της μεταβολής στο διάγραμμα $p-V$ ή από το αλγεβρικό άθροισμα των έργων των επιμέρους μεταβολών.\\
$\vartriangleright$ Από τον πρώτο θερμοδυναμικό νόμο αν γνωρίζουμε την αντίστοιχη θερμότητα $Q$ και τη μεταβολή της εσωτερικής ενέργειας $\Delta U$.\\
$\vartriangleright$ Αν η μεταβολή είναι τμήμα κάποιας κυκλικής μεταβολής και γνωρίζουμε το έργο των υπολοίπων μεταβολών του κύκλου καθώς και το συνολικό έργο όλου του κύκλου τότε το ζητούμενο έργο προκύπτει αν από το συνολικό έργο αφαιρέσουμε το έργο των υπολοίπων.\\ 
$\star$ Σε οποιαδήποτε αντιστρεπτή μεταβολή μεταξύ των καταστάσεων 1 και 2 ισχύει $$\boxed{\ W_{12}=-W_{21}\ }$$ 
{\sffamily \textcolor{Mahogany}{ 2. Θερμότητα αντιστρεπτής μεταβολής αερίου: }}\\  
Σε μια αντιστρεπτή μεταβολή η θερμότητα που ανταλλάσσει το αέριο μπορεί να υπολογιστεί\\ 
$\vartriangleright$ Αν η μεταβολή είναι ισόχωρη ή ισοβαρής από τις σχέσεις που ισχύουν σε κάθε περίπτωση.\\
$\vartriangleright$ Αν η μεταβολή είναι κυκλική από το εμβαδόν που περικλείεται από τη γραμμή της μεταβολής στο διάγραμμα $p-V$ ή από το αλγεβρικό άθροισμα των θερμοτήτων των επιμέρους μεταβολών.\\
$\vartriangleright$ Από τον πρώτο θερμοδυναμικό νόμο αν γνωρίζουμε το αντίστοιχο έργο $W$ και τη μεταβολή της εσωτερικής ενέργειας $\Delta U$. \\
$\vartriangleright$ Αν η μεταβολή είναι τμήμα κάποιας κυκλικής μεταβολής και γνωρίζουμε τη θερμότητα των υπολοίπων μεταβολών του κύκλου καθώς και τη συνολική θερμότητα όλου του κύκλου τότε η ζητούμενη θερμότητα προκύπτει αν από τη συνολική αφαιρέσουμε τη θερμότητα των υπολοίπων.\\ 
$\star$ Σε οποιαδήποτε αντιστρεπτή μεταβολή μεταξύ των καταστάσεων 1 και 2 ισχύει $$\boxed{\ Q_{12}=-Q_{21}\ }$$ 
{\sffamily\textcolor{Mahogany}{ 3. Μεταβολή της εσωτερικής ενέργειας αερίου: }}\\  
Η μεταβολή της εσωτερικής ενέργειας του αερίου μπορεί να υπολογιστεί\\
$\vartriangleright$ Από τη σχέση $\Delta U=nC_V\Delta T$ ανεξάρτητα από το είδος της μεταβολής.\\
$\vartriangleright$  Αν το αέριο είναι μονοατομικό από τη σχέση  $\displaystyle{\Delta U=\frac{3}{2}nR\Delta T}$.\\
$\vartriangleright$ Από τον πρώτο θερμοδυναμικό νόμο αν γνωρίζουμε το αντίστοιχο έργο $W$ και θερμότητα τη $Q$.\\
$\vartriangleright$ Αν η μεταβολή είναι τμήμα κάποιας κυκλικής μεταβολής και γνωρίζουμε τη μεταβολή της εσωτερικής ενέργειας των υπολοίπων μεταβολών του κύκλου τότε η ζητούμενη μεταβολή είναι αντίθετη από το αλγεβρικό άθροισμα των μεταβολών της εσωτερικής ενέργειας των υπολοίπων.\\
$\vartriangleright$ Από τη μεταβολή της εσωτερικής ενέργειας οποιασδήποτε άλλης μεταβολής μεταξύ της ίδιας αρχικής και τελικής θερμοκρασίας.\\
$\star$ Η μεταβολή της εσωτερικής ενέργειας σε μια κυκλική μεταβολή είναι μηδέν.\\
$\star$ Η μεταβολή της εσωτερικής ενέργειας σε μια σειρά μεταβολών μπορεί να υπολογιστεί είτε με έναν από τους παραπάνω τρόπους είτε ως αλγεβρικό άθροισμα των μεταβολών της εσωτερικής ενέργειας των επιμέρους μεταβολών.\\  
$\star$ Σε οποιαδήποτε αντιστρεπτή μεταβολή μεταξύ των καταστάσεων 1 και 2 ισχύει $$\boxed{\ \Delta U_{12}=-\Delta U_{21}\ }$$ 

\begin{table}
\small
\captionsetup{font=small,skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} 
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{10}{S[table-format=2.2]} }
    \toprule
     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Ισόθερμη} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Ισόχωρη} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Ισοβαρής}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Αδιαβατική}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Κυκλική}\\
    \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9} \cmidrule{10-11}
    & {\footnotesize{Εκτ.}} & {\footnotesize{Συμπ.}} & {\footnotesize{Θέρμ.}} & {\footnotesize{Ψύξη}} & {\footnotesize{Εκτ.}} & {\footnotesize{Συμπ.}} & {\footnotesize{Εκτ.}} & {\footnotesize{Συμπ.}} & {\footnotesize{Δεξ/φη}} & {\footnotesize{Αρ/φη}}\\
    \midrule
    {$p$} & {$\downarrow$} & {$\uparrow$} & {$\uparrow$} & {$\downarrow$} & {\footnotesize{σταθ.}} & {\footnotesize{σταθ.}} & {$\downarrow$} & {$\uparrow$} &  & \\
    \midrule
    {$V$} & {$\uparrow$} & {$\downarrow$} & {\footnotesize{σταθ.}} & {\footnotesize{σταθ.}} & {$\uparrow$} & {$\downarrow$} & {$\uparrow$} & {$\downarrow$}  & & \\
    \midrule
    {$T$} & {\footnotesize{σταθ.}} & {\footnotesize{σταθ.}} & {$\uparrow$} & {$\downarrow$} & {$\uparrow$} & {$\downarrow$} & {$\downarrow$} & {$\uparrow$} &  & \\
    \midrule
    {$Q$} & {+} & {$-$} & {+} & {$-$} & {+} & {$-$} & {0} & {0} & {+} & {$-$} \\
    \midrule
   {$\Delta U$} & {0} & {0} & {+} & {$-$} & {+} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {+} & {0} & {0} \\
    \midrule
{$W$} & {+} & {$-$} & {0} & {0} & {+} & {$-$} & {+} & {$-$} & {+} & {$-$} \\    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{shaded}









\begin{center}{\sffamily Παράδειγμα 4.3.1}\end{center}




\end{document}
```

Comment: Cannot find the error and don't have much time today...please help. maybe its something easy that i can see. The error is somewhere in the table environment that i wrote today.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Your code is a bit too long for a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). Could you remove not relevant parts? Edit your question and click on code style to improve the visulaisation of your code.

Comment: You can't use a table inside a shaded environment.

Comment: So simple...I am embarrassed...Thank you very much sir!

Comment: How i vote for your answer? its the minimum i can do.

Comment: I added my comment as answer. And I'm not a sir, but a madam.

Comment: What are you trying to realise, exactly?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a `table` environment inside a `shaded` environment.